# Problems with javascript inside echo

Tags: php, javascript

I want to echo the following code:

```
<a href="http://delicious.com/save" onclick="window.open('http://delicious.com/save?v=5&noui&jump=close&url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title), 'delicious','toolbar=no,width=550,height=550'); return false;" class="delicious" target="_blank">Add to Delicious</a>
```

The problem is that Dreamweaver warns me on syntax errors I can not figure out. Who can spot the syntax errors? The html and script on its own works just fine - the problem comes with the php when it is echoed.

Comment: there must be more to your php than just the above.

Comment: are you trying to echo it with php e.g echo 'a href=""etc'; ? if so you will need to escape any single or double quotes depending on what you enclose your string in. e.g echo "<a href=\"http://delicious.com/save\""; etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="http://delicious.com/save" onclick="window.open(\'http://delicious.com/save?v=5&noui&jump=close&url=\'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+\'&title=\'+encodeURIComponent(document.title), \'delicious\',\'toolbar=no,width=550,height=550\'); return false;" class="delicious" target="_blank">Add to Delicious</a>';
?>
```

not tested, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have `&` in HTML, these should be encoded to `&amp;`.

```
<a href="http://delicious.com/save" onclick="window.open('http://delicious.com/save?v=5&amp;noui&amp;jump=close&amp;url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title), 'delicious','toolbar=no,width=550,height=550'); return false;" class="delicious" target="_blank">Add to Delicious</a>
```

That's the only error I can spot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape " chars :

```
echo "<a href=\"http://delicious.com/save\" onclick=\"window.open('http://delicious.com/save?v=5&noui&jump=close&url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title), 'delicious','toolbar=no,width=550,height=550'); return false;\" class=\"delicious\" target=\"_blank\">Add to Delicious</a>";
```

As bluesmoon said it's better written as :

```
echo <<<ENDOFECHO
<a href="http://delicious.com/save" onclick="window.open('http://delicious.com/save?v=5&noui&jump=close&url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title), 'delicious','toolbar=no,width=550,height=550'); return false;" class="delicious" target="_blank">Add to Delicious</a>";
ENDOFECHO;
```

Comment: a HEREDOC would be better in this case